# makeindex does nothing, unless I copy .idx file to another directory

Tags: makeindex

My makefile for compiling my document runs `makeindex` after `pdflatex`. I recently noticed the index was no longer being emitted into the pdf, with no obvious cause (I didn't mess around with the document's major structure or preamble).

Here's what's weird: if I rollback the document sources to an earlier version (which definitely *did* produce a correct index) then the rolled-back version also has no index.

The log file contains

```
runsystem(makeindex book.idx)...executed.
```

Investigating, I see `book.idx` is being produced as expected from `book.pdf` (i.e. it has contents which reflect what the index ought to contain), but when I run `makeindex` in the output directory:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2015] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file book...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in book.ind.
Transcript written in book.ilg.
```

After this, `book.ind` is empty. However, if I do this

```
mkdir tmp
cp book.idx tmp
cd tmp
makeindex
```

then `book.ind` is created as expected, with what seem to be the correct Tex commands to render an index.

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2015] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file book.idx....done (10 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Sorting entries....done (31 comparisons).
Generating output file book.ind....done (28 lines written, 0 warnings).
Output written in book.ind.
Transcript written in book.ilg.
```

In a nutshell: if I run `makeindex` in a directory containing ***only*** `book.idx` then it works, otherwise it is as if `book.idx` is empty. The rest of the document is compiling and rendering correctly. What's up with `makeindex`?

Comment: This is difficult to track without seeing any line of code, but I suspect some issues with file permissions

Comment: It is pretty unclear, where, when, how often makeindex is called. If it is called in the `Makefile`, why does it appear in the `.log` file of `pdflatex`? Or do you use package `imakeidx` or run `makeindex` via the `\write18` feature? If the latter is true, it is run before or after `\makeindex`? At any case `book.idx` seems to be empty in the first case of the question. Is the output directory different from the source directory?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the command from `makeindex book` to `makeindex book.idx` seems to have fixed the issue.

I guess there was a package update.